# Using P-channel FET as switch

Tags: mosfet

I'm designing a charger circuit. When the input (+5v) is available it should disable the booster regulator by setting `Booster_en` to low. I used a single P-ch MOSFET like below circuit. I added pull-down to the gate of FET for when there is no (+5v) it turns on the FET and Booster_en gets high. I found many examples that use a pull-up circuit on FET's gate and some of them use a Schottky diode before `VCC`. Do I need to use two resistors or there are simpler ways? How about the diode?
[image]
EDIT:
Here is the first version of circuit that the problem was on `Booster_en` that becomes floating when `VUSB` is off. On the other side, I want to fully isolate `VBat` when `+5v` (VUSB) exists. I also removed the `Q4` transistor and connected R9 to ground. I think it is useless because when there is no VDD for charge it would turn off.
[image]

Comment: Need the rest of the circuit.  You want the gate referenced to the source and not to ground.

Comment: What is your battery voltage?  If you want Q1 to operate as an inverter then you have the drain and source reversed (as a hint, look at the intrinsic diode and ask yourself what it is going to do to `Booster_en` *all the time*).

Comment: @GeorgeHerold Added the circuit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I find the most reliable method of switching a PMOSFET is by using an NMOSFET. The circuit I generally tend to use is like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fc2phq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With this circuit, R1 is pulling up the gate of M1, keeping it off. R2 is pulling down the gate of M2, also keeping it off. Once the 5V is applied to the gate of M2, it will pull the gate of M1 low, which will allow M1 to enable the Boost_EN pin.

This is a circuit I have used many times and it has always been reliable.

**Edit due to addition of circuit in original question**

The original wording of the question sounded like the EN pin was needing to go HIGH when 5V was applied. Now it seems that the intention is for the pin to go LOW when 5V is applied. This simplifies things. Replace M1 with a pull-up resistor:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQlrYv.png)</sup>

With this circuit, your EN pin is always pulled HIGH by the resistor R1. When 5V is applied, M2 will pull the pin LOW.

Comment: Do you still think this fit with the new circuit? Is there any way that I can replace M2 with Q4? I want reverse logic. When 5v exist the Booster pin must be set low.

Comment: Ahh. The addition of your circuit has changed things. Your original description looked like you wanted the EN pin to go high when 5V was there. I'll edit my answer

Comment: @MasoudR. the answer is now updated

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way that I can isolate VBat when the +5v is on.
In the above circuit when +5V applies the R1 would drain VBat. But in my first circuit, VBat would be totally off the circuit. Am I right?

Comment: R1 doesn't need to be tied to Vbat. Tie it to the output if you want. As long as it holds the EN pin high until the MOSFET switches it low

Comment: So here is my problem. I can't connect R1 to output because the EN pin is floating so there output is low. I should first set EN to high.

Comment: Tie it elsewhere that's always high then

Answer (score 1):

Use a 1-gate inverter with 5V tolerant input and a VCC range that accommodates a single LiPo, powered off of VBatt, like an NC7SZ04.  No resistors, no transistor weirdness, just a working part.